# How to downgrade visual studio 2017 to 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, xamarin.winphone, xamarin.windows

I uninstalled visual studio 2015 to make way for 2017 but 2017 is not supporting xamarin.winphone so I would like to downgrade it to visual studio 2015 so that it supports xamarin winphone

I tried to find options to downgrade but I couldn't find any

My question is partly in relation with my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44143642/8053184)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 can co-exist with visual Studio 2017. Since you have install Visual Studio 2015, and just start it from 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Sure, create shortcut on your desktop for your next time......

Comment: Is there any place where I can download the older visual studio versions ?

Comment: If you have MSDN subscription, you can download it from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/ or https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/securedownloads/?#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=653&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0 .Otherwise, no! :-(

Comment: I don't have :( May be I have to download from thirdparty sites

Comment: can I use license from 2017 in 2015 ?